# Erro ao tentar autenticar em uma API laravel

Tags: laravel, api, autenticação

Estou tentar autenticar minha requisição em uma API Laravel (5.4) .
Mesmo seguindo a documentação de autenticação da documentação, sempre que envio a requisição, tenho o seguinte retorno:

> Not valid token provider.

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


public function login(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();
    $success = true;

    $user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();



    if ($user == null) {
        return $this->outputJSON(null, "Endereço de e-mail incorreto!", 404);
    } elseif (Hash::check($data['password'], $user->getAuthPassword())) {
        $user->remember_token = str_random(60);
        $user->save();

        $result = array(
            'message' => 'Login realizado com sucesso! ',
            'data' => $user,
            'success' => true,
        );
        return response()->json($result);
    } else {
        return $this->outputJSON(null, "Senha inválida", 404);
    }
}

 public function getLogout()
  {
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: O erro é bem claro `Not valid token provider` -  Nenhum provedor de token válido, ou seja, para a API lhe responder sem um 403 (acesso negado) é necessário enviar um token juntamente com a requisição.

Comment: O token não é obtido depois da autenticação?

Comment: Desculpe, fui muito genérico. Neste seu caso do login o que pode estar ocorrendo é um erro com a geração do Token, a resposta da API no caso. O Laravel possui um comando que é possível rodar para ele criar as rotas e funções de autenticação, tente rodar em outro projeto e comparar: `php artisan make:auth` (não rode no seu)

Comment: Pode estar faltando você devolver um token JWT, se é isto que você está utilizando. Não vejo um `new JwtAuth();` no seu Controller. Tenho um modelo, compare e veja se ajuda: https://gist.github.com/tiagoboeing/eafe457640b9732cf547e5e21fbf1246

Comment: Mesmo aplicando o JWT(), gerando o 'JWT_SECRET', continua a retornar  mesmo error.

Comment: Você está utilizando Postman para testar sua API?

Comment: Resolvi. Faltava apenas configurar o JWT. Obrigado, @TiagoBoeing

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Poste seu código como resposta e marque como resolvida. Caso meu código tenha sido a solução de seu problema posso respondê-la, porém imagino que você tenha personalizado para sua aplicação.